# Single color crest on glass

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-photoshop

I'm having a slow brain day. If anyone can point me in the right direction that would be great thanks.

I need to create the below crest as a single color graphic so that it can be printed onto a pint glass glass. I need it either black or white, no greys.

[image]

I can't seem to figure it out. The crest below is also the highest res available.

Comment: Select only the black stroke? Either that or you have to replace some of the colors with black, others with white, you have to decide which goes where. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: It's also quite a low res image for printing, you might need to resize it or redesign it (preferably on Illustrator)

Comment: Hi thanks for replying.

Basically I need it to look like this but with more definition/resolution.
https://imgur.com/a/WPrLBDA

I think I may have to remake it in illustrator as @Luciano suggested.

Comment: I second the comment by @Luciano. If you only have that low resolution raster image, then it's probably not enough. You may have to recreate/redraw it manually. I doubt if auto tracing will be good enough.

Comment: Why not search online for a better resolution? [Here](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=suttonians+rfc+logo&iax=images&ia=images) is a duckduckgo search for "suttonians rfc logo" and [here](http://www.ranklogos.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/Suttonians-RFC-Logo.jpg) is the best resolution I could find.